# Linux POSIX in C program fail in cancellation threads

Tags: c, linux, pthreads, posix, cancellation

I'm writing a program which reads portions of data in different threads then finds a pattern within them.

But before that (the problem occurs in code below) I just wanted to check whether threads cancel properly. That's where I'm stuck. It takes time to see an error, but basically after (sometimes 40 times) starting my program, it hangs in the while loop in main thread

```
while (alive_threads) { //never ends, because alive_threads==1, but pthread_cleanup_pop should make sure that all canceling threads reduces counter and as a result reduce it to 0
 usleep(1000);
}
```

... waiting for the last thread to cancel.

Code is here: http://pastebin.com/VqRrhXPD

I've also supplied content of file I'm reading from.

Opening:

```
./a.out 20 test.txt 40 clean

20 -number of threads

40 -portion of data
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are modifying the global variable `alive_threads` without any memory synchronization. This invokes undefined behavior; in all likelihood, it causes some of the decrements to be lost.

Comment: hm, thx for reply. But how they can be, just lost ? Just by creating another mutex only inside poping function where I decrement, I'll fix my problem?

Comment: They can be lost if two threads do a read/modify/write at the same time. You need to protect shared objects with a mutex.

Comment: @aragornsql: That's a good start and (though technically not 100% sufficient) will likely fix the problem.

Comment: @David Schwartz:Yep, it look fine now. I hope it's ok. But what do you mean by "not 100% sufficient"? Is there a better way, or there're some drawbacks ?

Comment: @aragornsql: Imagine if the compiler  implements`while (alive_threads)` by reading `alive_threads` from memory and then writing it back. A decrement could get lost.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: Huh? That's not valid per the POSIX and C11 memory models. Reads cannot write. The actual issue is that, in the absence of any synchronization, it could *cache* the value read and never re-read it, or that it could read a partially-written value.

Comment: @R..: Posix has no such requirement, as far as I know. And this isn't necessarily a C11 question. (But there are other ways it can fail anyway. That was just an example. The point is, nothing guarantees that it will work because one thread accesses an object while another thread might be modifying it, which is UB.)

Comment: As far as I know, POSIX does not have any requirement that prevents a read from corrupting an in-progress write (because it's UB anyway), but it does require that simultaneous reads be possible. I suppose what you're saying *could* be done if the read-write cycle never causes a corrupt value to be seen by other reading threads.

Comment: @R..: You don't have to try to think of ways it could fail. It's UB, period. The implementation can think of ways it can fail, it's not limited by our imagination. (However, it will likely fix the problem.)